# Sympy Solve For All Solutions On Domain

Tags: python, sympy, solver

For periodic functions, how do I tell `sympy` I want ALL the solutions on some domain?

Example:

```
import sympy
import sympy.parsing.sympy_parser

SympyExpression = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr( 'sin(pi* x)*sin(pi*y)' )
Variables = [sympy.Symbol('x'),sympy.Symbol('y') ]
Zeros = sympy.solve( f = SympyExpression, symbols = Variables )

print Zeros
```

Output:

```
 >>>> [{x: 0}, {x: 1}, {y: 0}, {y: 1}]
```

---

Clearly the solutions are correct but not complete.

What if I want all the zeros on the real domain:

```
-2 < x < 2
-2 < y < 2
```

Somehow it would be nice to get all the solutions on that domain:

```
 x = k -> k in [-2,-1,0,1,2]
 OR
 y = j -> j in [-2,-1,0,1,2]
```

For illustration I provide a [link to Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(pi*%20x)*sin(pi*y)) which graphs this 2D surface.

Comment: `solveset` would be your answer. It doesn't seem to handle this function, though, for [whatever reason](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11218).

Comment: solveset looks like it is supposed to solve my problem - maybe if I freeze myself and come back in 5 years?

Comment: Hopefully much sooner. We have two Google Summer of Code students working on it this summer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done directly, but there is a work-around (at least for this particular function you posted):

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
n = sympy.Symbol('n')

sol = sympy.solve('sin(pi*(x + n))*sin(pi*(y+n))', [x, y])
```

which gives:

```
[{x: -n}, {x: -n + 1}, {y: -n}, {y: -n + 1}]
```

So, clearly, for `n = 0` you obtain the standard solution. Now you can simply loop through your solutions for certain values of `n` and the filter the values that are in your desired range. E.g.

```
[sol2[0][x].subs(n, vali) for vali in range(-30, 40) if sol2[0][x].subs(n, vali) >= -2 and sol2[0][x].subs(n, vali) <= 2]
```

which gives you the desired output:

```
[2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
```

Of course, you then need to merge the different solutions you obtain for `x` and `y`, respectively, but this should get you on the right track.

Comment: I see - you can be clever and know in advance what the period of the function is?  There might exist a more general approach - where you do a .subs(var, var + n_var ), so you can automate the search. Ill circle back later today after trying this out.

Comment: @DAdams: Sure, there might be more general approaches. This one works fine for the problem you provided and should easily be adjustable to other periodic functions.

Comment: Also for your choice of n -> You would need to intoduce an n_x and an n_y with this method.

Comment: @DAdams: Yes, which would then be the same command as for `x`.

Comment: I guess I still don't know how the code would know that n is in the set of integers?

Comment: @DAdams: You loop through integers: `for vali in range(-30, 40)`. Then you check whether the result you get for `x` is in the desired range; that is all done in the list comprehension.

Comment: but HOW do you know to loop through integers? If I change the example to (x-2)*(x-7)*sin(y) or sin( x + y )  and ask about the same domain then this entire solution remains un-automated.

Comment: Sure, I know that this solution isn't perfect, that's why I wrote in the beginning " but there is a work-around (at least for this particular function you posted)". :)